# Laravel 5: TinyMCE 4 images have broken urls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tinymce

I just installed TinyMCE + jbimages plugin to be able to upload photos from the editor directly.
The upload works, but the display is breaking because of relative urls.

I add a blog post from 
`http://localhost/laravel-5/article/create` 
and uploading an image works and it even displays the image in the editor.

The image path in the editor says `../images/display-error1.jpg`

but after submitting it and going back to the blog's page `localhost/laravel-5/articles`

the image doesn't display. It's pointing to `localhost/laravel-5/images/image.jpg` and skipping `public` altogether.

This is the upload path config in `tinymce/plugins/jbimages/config.php`

```
$config['img_path'] = '/laravel-5/public/images'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path'];
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_base_path

Just add `images_upload_base_path: '/base/path/to-images'`